# terraform create pub/sub on gcp gives error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, publish-subscribe

I have the following terraform file

```
provider "google" {  
  project     = "prj1-user"
  region      = "APAC"
  zone        = "australia-southeast1-a"
}

resource "google_pubsub_topic" "prj1-messages" {
  name = "prj1Messages" 
  labels = {
    foo = "bar"
  }  
}
```

however when I try to provision this through `terraform apply` I get the following error

```
│ Error: Error creating Topic: Put "https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/prj1-user/topics/prj1Messages?alt=json": oauth2/google: invalid token JSON from metadata: EOF
│ 
│   with google_pubsub_topic.brwmessages,
│   on main.tf line 7, in resource "google_pubsub_topic" "prj1Messages":
│    7: resource "google_pubsub_topic" "prj1Messages" {
```

The version I'm using is

```
Terraform v1.0.0
on linux_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google v3.71.0
```

Comment: Where are you running the Terraform code? Your problem is no permission/authorization which means you either need to run this code on a Google Cloud compute service, specify a service account in the Terraform code, or set up ADC (Application Default Credentials). Edit your question with details on your environment.

Comment: Note: This error message `oauth2/google: invalid token JSON from metadata: EOF` indicates that you are running this code on Compute Engine, but the scopes are disabled.